# how to expand a string into multiple rows in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want to split a string into multiple rows.

```
df.assign(MODEL_ABC = df['MODEL_ABC'].str.split('_').explode('MODEL_ABC'))

my output:
        YEAR   PERIOD   MODEL_ABC     Price       Qty
0      2018      First       A       75.0       25.0
```

if i run individually for column i'm getting  like below but not entire dataframe
A
B

```
this is my dataframe df

        YEAR   PERIOD   MODEL_ABC     Price       Qty
0      2018      First       A_B       75.0       25.0

expected output:

        YEAR   PERIOD   MODEL_ABC     Price       Qty
0      2018      First       A       75.0       25.0
1      2018      First       B       75.0       25.0
```

Comment: Try: ``df.assign(MODEL_ABC = df.MODEL_ABC.str.split("_")).explode('MODEL_ABC')``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following, start by transforming the column into a list, so then you can [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) it to create multiple rows:

```
df['MODEL_ABC'] = df['MODEL_ABC'].str.split('_')
df = df.explode('MODEL_ABC')
```